# Dnsmasq: Consider all responses

Tags: dnsmasq

I have set up a dnsmasq server and enabled the `--all-servers` flag to query all servers. My problem is, that by default, dnsmasq won't consider all responses. It would stop after the first one, whether it is positive or negative. I know that this is the intended behavior for e.g. web nameservers which all know the same hosts but I have a different setup.

Is there any kind of way to enable this and evaluate all responses?

Thanks in advance!